# I want to remove the last end sign from the end of the list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

```
>>> for i in range(4):
...     print(i, end=" :-) ")
...
0 :-) 1 :-) 2 :-) 3 :-) >>>
```

I want to remove the last :-) after 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three reasonable ways to do this.

The first is to explicitly examine the values you're iterating on to decide what kind of `end` you want to pass to `print`. Since you're iterating directly on a `range`, this is pretty easy, just test for the last value:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(i, end=" :-) " if i < 3 else "\n")
```

I used a "ternary" expression (`x if c else y`) to switch the smiley for a newline to follow the last value. If your `range` was not always the same size (e.g. it was `range(x)`), you could test `i < x-1` in the conditional expression.

The second approach is to use `str.join` to combine your items into a single string with the separators already baked in, then pass the single string to `print` with no special `end` argument:

```
print(" :-) ".join(str(i) for i in range(4)))
```

The last option is available in Python 3 (and in the later versions of Python 2 if you use `from __future__ import print_function` to get the Python 3 version of `print`). It is to use argument unpacking to pass the whole `range` of numbers to the `print` function at once, and pass the smiley as the `sep` argument rather than `end`:

```
print(*range(4), sep=" :-) ")
```

This is probably the nicest solution. Enabling this kind of code was one of the main reasons that `print` became a function in Python 3 (you couldn't unpack a sequence as arguments to the Python 2 `print` statement).